# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, dns

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm trying to learn how to have specs/ services and domain projects in general but in this case it's ASP.NET MVC.

I have the following code in my controller but I getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object on the following line of code.  I would appreciate any suggestions where I'm going wrong!?

```
// Error
Line 22:             var profiles = _profileService.GetProfile();


// code below

namespace Whitepages.Controllers
{
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProfileService _profileService;

    public HomeController(IProfileService profileService)
    {
        _profileService = profileService;
    }

    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var profiles = _profileService.GetProfile();
        return View("Index");
    }

}
}

using Domain;

namespace Services.Spec
{
    public interface IProfileService
    {
        Profile GetProfile();
    }
}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: are you uusing any IOC containrs if no where is new object for profileService is created? public HomeController(IProfileService profileService)
    {
        _profileService = profileService;
    }

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the controller factory you are using to build your controllers passes null at the constructor of HomeController. In ASP.NET MVC controllers are built by a controller factory which by default is the [`DefaultControllerFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx) class which simply invokes the default constructor.

The fact that you are getting a `NullReferenceException` instead of *the class HomeController doesn't have a default constructor* indicates that you have setup a custom controller factory in your `Global.asax` which is supposed to provide instances of your controllers but this custom controller factory doesn't passes null to the HomeController constructor, so when later you try to access this service `_profileService.GetProfile()` you get the exception. You are probably using some dependency injection framework and in your `Application_Start` you have something like this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SomeCustomControllerFactory());
```

So if you are using a DI framework you need to setup this framework to pass a specific implementation of the `IProfileService` interface to the constructor. How this is done would totally depend on the framework you are using.

Comment: im not sure what factory im using although I am using the default mvc 2.0

Comment: @James Radford, well then you need to use a factory or the framework wouldn't know how to instantiate your controller. You need to have a class that implements the `IProfileService` and then have a custom controller factory which would supply this dependency. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://nayyeri.net/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc). And here's [another one](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Simple-Dependency-Injection-using-a-Custom-MVC-Controller-Factory.aspx).